# Is there a way to make my planet go slow mode or fast mode in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I an making a solar system with physics and I want to make the time faster through a variable called `timeChange`. I want to control the variable through sliders. I did `planet.pos.add(timeChange)` but it is not working and I tried deferent methods those also didn't work.

Comment: Could you possibly show the part of the code that makes the planets move?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function frameRate(time change)? It controls the number of frames per second thet your program is making.

Comment: Yes I did it But it only makes the animation smoother

Comment: What do you mean? Did you try changing the value of the variable? Please read this page if you haven't already https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate